# Excel Alternative to nested IF

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, wildcard, countif

I have a couple of rather large nested if functions in my spreadsheet. It sure would be nice to have an alternative method. Problem is I'm using a wildcard (*) in my lookup because the source text has slight variations (date for example).

For example, if my list of data contains:

```
VENMO PAYMENT 220828 1022093447487 BRENDA HOSPY
VENMO PAYMENT 220813 1031323447487 BRENDA HOSPY
```

I want these to show in an adjacent column of cells as just Venmo

Currently my if function in that second column of cells is:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($F10,"*APPLE.COM/BILL*"),"AP",
IF(COUNTIF($F10,"IIA VOYA*"),"VOYA",
IF(COUNTIF($F10,"VENMO PAYMENT*"),"Venmo",
IF(COUNTIF($F10,etc...
```

This works fine but quickly gets unruly as more things get added.

I've spent a great deal of time searching for functions and processes that would make this easier, or at least more compact, but I can't find a way with typical functions like vlookup or index/match.

If I've explained this in a comprehensible fashion perhaps you've seen or experienced a similar situation and could offer a suggestion. It would be appreciated!

I'm not opposed to using a programming function.

I've looked at, and for, various Excel functions or combinations with no luck on my own or online.

Comment: create a mapping table with two columns "source name" and "new name" - then you can use `INDEX/MATCH`

Comment: I agree. When I get into a pickle like this, generally speaking the best solution is to transform the data before doing the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a structure as below

[image]

Formula present in B2 is as below

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$2:$F$9,MIN(IF(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$E$2:$E$9&"*")>0,ROW($E$2:$E$9),9999999)-1)),"---")
```

Enter it as an Array Formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter
It will search all the strings present in column E in A2 when found will return all the row numbers of column E where there is a match, i have then used min to get the first one, and if not found it will return 9999999, and as the data is starting from row 2 i have added -1 to make it equal to the data index. after that i have called the index to search value present at that index in column F. and at the end used the if error function to show --- where no match was found and 999999 was returned.

Comment: This works perfectly for what I want to do and you also gave me a couple hints on stuff I can use elsewhere, thank you so much!